# NeutralinoJS Open local html file in browser

Tags: javascript, neutralinojs

In my Neutralino app I have a navigation. When I click on a specific navigation item, I want a local html to open in the browser (or new window).
The html file to open is in a subfolder of my app resources directory.

My first approach was to call the relative URL in the main.js file via Neutralino.app.open (in my config.json "url" is set to "/resources/"), without success.

```
window.myApp = {
openDocumentation: () => {
  Neutralino.app.open({
    "url": "/help/help.html"
  });
}
}
```

Next I tried to get the local app path to set an absolute path.

```
async function getStartupDir(){
    let response = await Neutralino.os.execCommand({
        command: 'CD'
    });
    return response.output;
}

window.myApp = {
openDocumentation: () => {
  getStartupDir().then(myValue => {
    myValue = myValue.replace(/\\/g,"/");               
    Neutralino.app.open({
      "url": "http://"+myValue+"help/help.html"
    });
  });       
}
}
```

That does not work either.

Is there any way to achieve this with neutralinojs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer myself.
In Neutralino there is a global variable `NL_CWD` that contains the app path. With that path I can directly open the local html file in browser via file:/// ...

The solution:

```
window.myApp = {
  openDocumentation: () => {    
    Neutralino.app.open({
      "url": "file:///"+NL_CWD+"/resources/help/help.html"
    });
  }
}
```

And of course:

```
window.myApp.openDocumentation();
```